# An easy way to disable the red icon for inbox notifications

Tags: support, global-inbox

[image: Screenshot of top bar with inbox red flashy thing circled, as opposed to the review red flashy thing]

I want to disable inbox notifications on all SE sites (which you may or may not find valid but that is not the point) but it appears that the software does not provide an easy way to do that.

Is there some easy (i.e. noob-friendly) way to prevent the inbox from displaying the red notification? Some kind of script or whatever programmers call it, or a browser extension maybe? I really do find it distracting.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of one of the red flashy thing. There's actually *two* red flashy things, so if I've circled the wrong red flashy thing, let me know